# How do I set up a custom JDK build in sdkman?

Tags: java, sdkman, project-loom

I was able to play around with the latest early access binary for Project Loom by downloading the file from http://jdk.java.net/loom/, extracting it (I had a directory called `jdk-18`), setting the `JAVA_HOME` env var to the `jdk-18` directory, and adding the `bin` subdirectory for the build to the beginning of my `PATH` env var. I was able to use the build to compile and run a Java program using the virtual thread preview features.

But this feels like a very manual process. I like how SDKMAN manages JDKs on my system. How can I set up this early access build (or any other JDK build for that matter) as an entry in the list of JDKs managed by SDKMAN, so that I could change to it, for example, by typing `sdk default java <my-jdk-18-name>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDKMAN has a feature called "Install Local Version(s)" (https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion).

So, to set up a custom build of the JDK with SDKMAN, I can download and install the JDK wherever I want and then link it to SDKMAN so that it's useable like any other JDK managed by SDKMAN:

```
wget https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/7/openjdk-18-loom+7-288_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
tar -xf openjdk-18-loom+7-288_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
mv jdk-18/ 18-loom
sdk install java 18-loom $(realpath 18-loom/)
```

After installing and linking:

```
~/javas > sdk default java 18-loom

Default java version set to 18-loom
~/javas > which java
/home/matt/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java
~/javas > java --version
openjdk 18-loom 2022-03-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18-loom+7-288)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18-loom+7-288, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Joggling PATH variable for managing mulptiple JDK's was the only straightforward way of doing things for many years, however general automation of this process slowly improves.

Currently on I use [jenv](https://www.jenv.be/), generally any POSIX OS should be supported, I use it on Mac (`brew install jenv`).

Its main drawback for me — if you include its init `$(jenv init -)` in terminal RC script, it will delay terminal start-up for a few seconds.

Switch for particular folder would look like:
`jenv local <my-custom-jdk-name>`

Comment: Ah, so is the idea that I'd run something like `jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home` (from their home page example) for the directory where I extract my custom build to, like the jdk-18 Project Loom build I reference in my question? jenv requires me to install the JDK, but then once I have, it can manage any JDK I've installed, not just ones from a registry (like sdkman)?

Comment: Actually, I found a way to do it with sdkman by looking through their GitHub issues: https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/1016#issuecomment-997524195